# All images on one line for each post

Tags: posts, attachments, media-library, formatting

Having trouble getting around the issue where my client wants all of the images for each post to be on one line. This can be done in the editor, but they are not very tech savvy -- just wants to be able to type a blurb, and then add a series of photos, and have them all sit on a single line.

Is there a wordpress php file or a hook/override I can use to make it so all the

tags containing images float left and add a clear:both at the end of this?

I noticed that there's selectable format's for the post -- would it be here that I would do this?

Also -- I saw a doc showing how the format works and it looks like it just changes the structure of the title & content. How can I edit the structure of the actual post content since that's where the images exist?

Answer (score 1):

Just click Gallery--->"insert gallery" .

To change styles you edit the CSS file. If the theme is coded correctly post images will have a unique CSS class.

Comment: Where is this 'gallery' that you speak of?

Comment: When you click "add image" there is a gallery tab. Or you can use the shortcode `[gallery]`

Comment: Ohh I see, yeah I understand adding images, but it seems that when it's rendered on the page, each image has a wrapping <p> tag, and these <p> tags keep the images from aligning in a line. Is there a default way I can have images align to the left without having my client click Align: Left each time?